# Send mysql query with just a click

Tags: php, javascript

I can send a query to mysql database with following code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('', '$message', '$replyno')");
```

My questions is, Is there any way to send a query with just a click on some text.

**Let's example:** there are a text name Reply. I want if i click this Reply text then mysql database field value (**field name: Reply, type: int**) will be increase by 1.

**Sorry I DON'T KNOW ABOUT JAVASCRIPT/AJAX:(**

**FINAL UPDATER CODE TO @DEVELOPER:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
$("#mylink").click(function() {
$.ajax({
url: "test.php"
}).done(function() { 
$(this).addClass("done");
});
});
</script>
<body>
echo "<a href='#' id='mylink'>Reply</a>";
</body>
</html>
Php page:
<?php
include("database/db.php");
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('','','','','','','','1');");
?>
```

Comment: you can use this using jquery and php////

Comment: Yes, there is a way, you can use html form or ajax

Comment: You would use $__Session , $__get[....] variables on a page request but you should escape your SQL queries to prevent xss.

Comment: Be careful of SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Step one: use mysqli instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this link or button to be clicked wired to an ajax call using jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It should call a php page, which contains the query you're looking to run. You can pass in arguments with the ajax call as well, so that your $message and $replyno are set properly before executing.

```
<script>
$("#mylink").click(function() {
  $data = $("#myform").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "postquery.php",
    data: $data
  }).done(function() { 
     $(this).addClass("done");
  });
});
</script>
```

then your php page would look something like this:

```
<?php
...
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['message']);
$replyno = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['replyno']);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('', '$message', '$replyno')");
....
?>
```

Excaping your incoming strings using "mysql_real_escape_string" is always important to prevent SQL Injection attacks on your database.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<html>
...
<input type="textarea"></input>
<a href="#" id="mylink">Reply</a>
...
</html>
```

This will cause the previously stated jquery statement to trigger when "Reply" is clicked.

Here is with your updated code. I corrected the link ID and also removed the form serialization data since your test code does not appear to need it. I also added the reference to the jQuery library:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$("#mylink").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php"
  }).done(function() { 
     $(this).addClass("done");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href='#' id='mylink'>Reply</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The problems you're likely seeing are because of your query, not the front end code. Try adding some debug code like this:

```
<?php
include("database/db.php");
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('','','','','','','','1');");
if(!$sql)
{
  echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Or try checking your servers error logs.

Comment: Thanks @Developer. But I just want to add reply value not message. If anyonce click the "Reply text" then only Mysql database reply field value increase..

Comment: If you're looking for an ID to increase by one, you should probably be using a AUTO_INCREMENT field in mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. If not, you'll have to be more specific as to what you're trying to do. Thanks

Comment: I know how to use auto-increment. But how do i send a query with just a click on Reply text.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the html which would be needed as well in order to trigger the ajax call.

Comment: is it require to use <script> your code </script> tag for $("#mylink").click(function() ?

Comment: Yes, any javascript would need to be in the <Script> tags. You also need to include the jquery library in your html page: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: The issue with it is your link ID should be set to "mylink" in order to correctly wire up with the jquery code. See my code update.

Comment: It's working FINE but it's going to test.php page after click the "Reply text". Is it possible to stay the same page.

Comment: The code I posted will not navigate away, make sure it is the same. If your "href" on the link is anything other than "#" it will change the page instead of loading it with the ajax only.

Comment: See my code again, the references to jquery were missing in your example.

Comment: The front end code should be fine, I'd imagine this problem is with your PHP code / query to the database. I added some advice for debugging this. The PHP error log would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall VALUES('', '$message', '$replyno')");
```

You have to use jquery and ajax like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#reply').click(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
                url: "test.php", //Your url detail
                type: 'POST' ,
                data: ,
                success: function(response){
   }
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file "updat_post.php" write:

```
If(isset($_GET['visit_post']))
     $pdo->query('update posts set counter = counter+1');
```

In your js/jquery file on document ready write:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $.post('update_post.php', {visit_post: true});
});
```